# Generating Invoice Using Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on ERP in Asp.net web form and Crystal Report for generating invoices. But I'm facing a problem while displaying the output: It automatically duplicating each data on page and listing whole table data.

[image]

**Note:** creating new connection using ODBC(RDO) and it was success.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and SAP Crystal Reports 2016

Comment: May you show the design and data schema?

Comment: Show your 'Design' tab - schema.